# How to get all animations on a component to be able to destroy them before finishing?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library

When I select an *element* on my page, I am requesting Json and *firing* off animations for page transitions using `goog.fx.dom.FadeInAndShow` and `goog.fx.dom.FadeOutAndHide`.

If one were to click on an element, and then quickly clicks on a different element, the request is canceled and the data from the most recent click is populated, however, the animations are not quite finished from the previous click,  which cause the incoming information the be effected by the prior animations `END`.

I'm wondering if there is something like `getAnimations` on the component that would have the animations and then be able to `.destroy()` them before they finish.

Answer (score 1):

If your animations are tied to a goog.ui.Component (or any other object that extends goog.Disposable), then after creating each animation, you could register the animation with the component via the component/disposable's registerDisposable() method.

That way, you could dispose the component (by invoking its dispose() method), which would invoke dispose() on all Disposables registered with it. Looking at goog.fx.Animation, when dispose() is invoked, its stop() method is invoked, so I believe this should work.

You could also just create a goog.Disposable for the purpose of registering animations on it and disposing all of them from one place. That said, if you register a lot of animations and don't call dispose until long after they are needed, you will have a memory leak because this will prevent the Animations from being garbage collected.